# How to use a Monad Transformer when Disjunction is the outermost container?

Tags: scala, monads, monad-transformers, scalaz7

```
val vLInts = (1 to 10).toList.right[String]

for {
  i <- ListT(vLints)
  _ = println(i)
} yield i

//error: no type parameters for method apply:(underlying: M[List[A]])scalaz.ListT[M,A] in object ListT exist so that it can be applied to arguments (scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]])
```

The problem here is that a disjunction `\/[A, B]` has 2 generics and therefore isn't a Monad.  When i make a type alias

```
type Attempt[A] = \/[String, A]
```

it succeeds, because I've held the left side fixed and I now have  Monad.  How can I get my Monad Transformer to work if the outermost type is a Disjunction, without resorting to type aliasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for{
i <- ListT[({type l[+a] = String \/ a})#l,Int](vLints)
_ = println(i)
} yield i
```

Apparently, the answer was a type lambda.  It's not pretty but it works.